# how to create multiple txt/php files from a list of names?

Tags: php, wordpress, shell, batch-file, scripting

I have a text file call newsites.txt in it are a bunch of names that I want to use to create a new wp-config.php file (wordpress file).

content of newsites.txt

```
    UserName:DatabaseName:DatabasePassword
    UserName2:DatabaseName2:DatabasePassword2
```

content of the wp-config.php

```
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
    /** MySQL database username */
    define('DB_USER', 'username_here');
    /** MySQL database password */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');
```

I just need  to replace those 3 fields in the wp-config.php and save it as *UserName*-wp-config.php and loop through the rest of the list.

any ideas what i can use to do automate this? I tried looking for batch script but have no idea how to do a 'find and replace' codes within a php file. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify the wp-config.php file? If so, then you can use an interesting trick that allows to solve this problem in a very simple way. In this problem you use the wp-config.php as a *template* and you want to replace text at certain given places. The trick consist in put at those places the *name of Batch variables* enclosed in exclamation marks, and enable Delayed Expansion; for example:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '!database_name_here!');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '!username_here!');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '!password_here!');
```

This way, when the lines of the file be displayed, each `!variable_name!` will be *automatically replaced* by the value of the variable! This method avoids to explicitly seek for each string and change it by each replacement value.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all lines in newsites.txt
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in (newsites.txt) do (

   rem Assign values for the corresponding variables
   set "username_here=%%a"
   set "database_name_here=%%b"
   set "password_here=%%c"

   rem Using the values of previous variables
   rem just read and write the lines in wp-config.php;
   rem the variables will be replaced by their values because Delayed Expansion
   (for /F "delims=" %%d in (wp-config.php) do (
      echo %%d
   )) > "!username_here!-wp-config.php"
   echo "!username_here!-wp-config.php" file created

)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat
"UserName-wp-config.php" file created
"UserName2-wp-config.php" file created

C:\> type UserName-wp-config.php
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'DatabaseName');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'UserName');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DatabasePassword');

C:\> type UserName2-wp-config.php
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'DatabaseName2');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'UserName2');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DatabasePassword2');
```

Comment: Aacini,

OMG OMG, you are a genius! The batch script work flawlessly. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple PHP script:

```
<?
$template = file_get_contents("wp-config.php");
$arrSearch = [ "database_name_here", "username_here", "password_here" ];
$content = file_get_contents("newsites.txt");
$arrLines = explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $content));

foreach ($arrLines as $line) {
    $arrLine = explode(":", $line);
    $userName = $arrLine[0];
    $dbName = $arrLine[1];
    $password = $arrLine[2];

    $arrReplace = [ $dbName, $userName, $password ];
    $new = str_replace($arrSearch, $arrReplace, $template);
    $filename = "{$userName}-wp-config.php";
    file_put_contents($filename, $new);
}
```